# Bring all child nodes under one parent node and sum child nodes Quantities

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, template-specialization

## I have below xml structure :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<peci:Worker_Effective_Stack_Aggregate xmlns:peci="urn:com.workday/peci">
    <peci:Workers_Effective_Stack xmlns:peci="urn:com.workday/peci">
        <peci:Summary>
            <peci:Integration_Event>c6d63dc4fdef100c76819f66b6b40000</peci:Integration_Event>
            <peci:Integration_Sent_On>2022-08-04T09:41:28.451-07:00</peci:Integration_Sent_On>
            <peci:Payroll_Company_ID>FP9_PayGroup</peci:Payroll_Company_ID>
            <peci:Payroll_Company_Name>Test</peci:Payroll_Company_Name>
            <peci:Payroll_Company_Code>FP9</peci:Payroll_Company_Code>
            <peci:Pay_Group_ID>SAL6</peci:Pay_Group_ID>
            <peci:Pay_Group_Name>USA Hourly</peci:Pay_Group_Name>
            <peci:Pay_Group_Country>US</peci:Pay_Group_Country>
            <peci:Pay_Group_Code>SAL6</peci:Pay_Group_Code>
            <peci:Pay_Period_Start>2022-07-25-07:00</peci:Pay_Period_Start>
            <peci:Pay_Period_End>2022-08-08-07:00</peci:Pay_Period_End>
            <peci:Updated_From>2022-08-01T21:00:00.000-07:00</peci:Updated_From>
            <peci:Updated_To>2022-08-04T09:41:28.451-07:00</peci:Updated_To>
            <peci:Effective_From>2022-07-25-07:00</peci:Effective_From>
            <peci:Effective_To>2022-08-08-07:00</peci:Effective_To>
            <peci:Change_Detection>Include only changes entered since the last successful run.</peci:Change_Detection>
            <peci:First_Primary_Run_of_Pay_Period>0</peci:First_Primary_Run_of_Pay_Period>
            <peci:Ad_Hoc_Run>1</peci:Ad_Hoc_Run>
            <peci:Full_Snapshot>0</peci:Full_Snapshot>
            <peci:Worker_Count>1</peci:Worker_Count>
            <peci:Version>1</peci:Version>
        </peci:Summary>
        <peci:Worker>
            <peci:Worker_Summary>
                <peci:WID>25d029d887251010f83dc895aa6a0000</peci:WID>
                <peci:Employee_ID>123567</peci:Employee_ID>
                <peci:Name>Mickey Mouse</peci:Name>
            </peci:Worker_Summary>
            <peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="2">
                <peci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
                <peci:Effective_Moment>2022-07-18T00:00:00.000-07:00</peci:Effective_Moment>
                <peci:Entry_Moment>2022-08-04T05:39:14.444-07:00</peci:Entry_Moment>
                <peci:Time_Tracking peci:isUpdated="1">
                    <peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>TimeTrack_Regular</peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>
                    <peci:External_Payroll_Code>RG</peci:External_Payroll_Code>
                    <peci:Override_Rate>0</peci:Override_Rate>
                    <peci:Time_Tracking_Entry peci:isUpdated="1">
                        <peci:Quantity peci:priorValue="14">15.5</peci:Quantity>
                    </peci:Time_Tracking_Entry>
                </peci:Time_Tracking>
                <peci:Additional_Information>
                    <peci:WorkerID>25d029d887251010f83dc895aa6a0000</peci:WorkerID>
                    <ptdf:FileID xmlns:ptdf="urn:com.workday/peci/tdf">005907</ptdf:FileID>
                </peci:Additional_Information>
            </peci:Effective_Change>
            <peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="4">
                <peci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
                <peci:Effective_Moment>2022-07-20T00:00:00.000-07:00</peci:Effective_Moment>
                <peci:Entry_Moment>2022-08-04T05:39:14.444-07:00</peci:Entry_Moment>
                <peci:Time_Tracking peci:isUpdated="1">
                    <peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>TimeTrack_OT1.5</peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>
                    <peci:External_Payroll_Code>OT</peci:External_Payroll_Code>
                    <peci:Override_Rate>0</peci:Override_Rate>
                    <peci:Time_Tracking_Entry peci:isUpdated="1">
                        <peci:Quantity peci:priorValue="0">3</peci:Quantity>
                    </peci:Time_Tracking_Entry>
                </peci:Time_Tracking>
                <peci:Time_Tracking peci:isUpdated="1">
                    <peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>TimeTrack_Regular</peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>
                    <peci:External_Payroll_Code>RG</peci:External_Payroll_Code>
                    <peci:Override_Rate>0</peci:Override_Rate>
                    <peci:Time_Tracking_Entry peci:isUpdated="1">
                        <peci:Quantity peci:priorValue="12">9.5</peci:Quantity>
                    </peci:Time_Tracking_Entry>
                </peci:Time_Tracking>
                <peci:Additional_Information>
                    <peci:WorkerID>25d029d887251010f83dc895aa6a0000</peci:WorkerID>
                    <ptdf:FileID xmlns:ptdf="urn:com.workday/peci/tdf">005907</ptdf:FileID>
                </peci:Additional_Information>
            </peci:Effective_Change>
            <peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="5">
                <peci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
                <peci:Effective_Moment>2022-07-26T00:00:00.000-07:00</peci:Effective_Moment>
                <peci:Entry_Moment>2022-08-04T09:10:37.351-07:00</peci:Entry_Moment>
                <peci:Time_Tracking peci:isUpdated="1">
                    <peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>TimeTrack_Regular</peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>
                    <peci:External_Payroll_Code>RG</peci:External_Payroll_Code>
                    <peci:Override_Rate>0</peci:Override_Rate>
                    <peci:Time_Tracking_Entry peci:isUpdated="1">
                        <peci:Quantity peci:priorValue="0">12</peci:Quantity>
                    </peci:Time_Tracking_Entry>
                </peci:Time_Tracking>
                <peci:Additional_Information>
                    <peci:WorkerID>25d029d887251010f83dc895aa6a0000</peci:WorkerID>
                    <ptdf:FileID xmlns:ptdf="urn:com.workday/peci/tdf">005907</ptdf:FileID>
                </peci:Additional_Information>
            </peci:Effective_Change>
            <peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="6">
                <peci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
                <peci:Effective_Moment>2022-07-27T00:00:00.000-07:00</peci:Effective_Moment>
                <peci:Entry_Moment>2022-08-04T09:10:37.351-07:00</peci:Entry_Moment>
                <peci:Time_Tracking peci:isUpdated="1">
                    <peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>TimeTrack_Regular</peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>
                    <peci:External_Payroll_Code>RG</peci:External_Payroll_Code>
                    <peci:Override_Rate>0</peci:Override_Rate>
                    <peci:Time_Tracking_Entry peci:isUpdated="1">
                        <peci:Quantity peci:priorValue="0">12</peci:Quantity>
                    </peci:Time_Tracking_Entry>
                </peci:Time_Tracking>
                <peci:Additional_Information>
                    <peci:WorkerID>25d029d887251010f83dc895aa6a0000</peci:WorkerID>
                    <ptdf:FileID xmlns:ptdf="urn:com.workday/peci/tdf">005907</ptdf:FileID>
                </peci:Additional_Information>
            </peci:Effective_Change>
            <peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="7">
                <peci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
                <peci:Effective_Moment>2022-07-28T00:00:00.000-07:00</peci:Effective_Moment>
                <peci:Entry_Moment>2022-08-04T09:10:37.351-07:00</peci:Entry_Moment>
                <peci:Time_Tracking peci:isUpdated="1">
                    <peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>TimeTrack_Regular</peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>
                    <peci:External_Payroll_Code>RG</peci:External_Payroll_Code>
                    <peci:Override_Rate>0</peci:Override_Rate>
                    <peci:Time_Tracking_Entry peci:isUpdated="1">
                        <peci:Quantity peci:priorValue="0">14</peci:Quantity>
                    </peci:Time_Tracking_Entry>
                </peci:Time_Tracking>
                <peci:Additional_Information>
                    <peci:WorkerID>25d029d887251010f83dc895aa6a0000</peci:WorkerID>
                    <ptdf:FileID xmlns:ptdf="urn:com.workday/peci/tdf">005907</ptdf:FileID>
                </peci:Additional_Information>
            </peci:Effective_Change>
            <peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="8">
                <peci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
                <peci:Effective_Moment>2022-07-29T00:00:00.000-07:00</peci:Effective_Moment>
                <peci:Entry_Moment>2022-08-04T09:10:37.351-07:00</peci:Entry_Moment>
                <peci:Time_Tracking peci:isUpdated="1">
                    <peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>TimeTrack_OT1.5</peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>
                    <peci:External_Payroll_Code>OT</peci:External_Payroll_Code>
                    <peci:Override_Rate>0</peci:Override_Rate>
                    <peci:Time_Tracking_Entry peci:isUpdated="1">
                        <peci:Quantity peci:priorValue="0">11</peci:Quantity>
                    </peci:Time_Tracking_Entry>
                </peci:Time_Tracking>
                <peci:Time_Tracking peci:isUpdated="1">
                    <peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>TimeTrack_Regular</peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>
                    <peci:External_Payroll_Code>RG</peci:External_Payroll_Code>
                    <peci:Override_Rate>0</peci:Override_Rate>
                    <peci:Time_Tracking_Entry peci:isUpdated="1">
                        <peci:Quantity peci:priorValue="0">2</peci:Quantity>
                    </peci:Time_Tracking_Entry>
                </peci:Time_Tracking>
                <peci:Additional_Information>
                    <peci:WorkerID>25d029d887251010f83dc895aa6a0000</peci:WorkerID>
                    <ptdf:FileID xmlns:ptdf="urn:com.workday/peci/tdf">005907</ptdf:FileID>
                </peci:Additional_Information>
            </peci:Effective_Change>
            <peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="9">
                <peci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
                <peci:Effective_Moment>2022-07-30T00:00:00.000-07:00</peci:Effective_Moment>
                <peci:Entry_Moment>2022-08-04T09:10:37.351-07:00</peci:Entry_Moment>
                <peci:Time_Tracking peci:isUpdated="1">
                    <peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>TimeTrack_OT1.5</peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>
                    <peci:External_Payroll_Code>OT</peci:External_Payroll_Code>
                    <peci:Override_Rate>0</peci:Override_Rate>
                    <peci:Time_Tracking_Entry peci:isUpdated="1">
                        <peci:Quantity peci:priorValue="0">15</peci:Quantity>
                    </peci:Time_Tracking_Entry>
                </peci:Time_Tracking>
                <peci:Additional_Information>
                    <peci:WorkerID>25d029d887251010f83dc895aa6a0000</peci:WorkerID>
                    <ptdf:FileID xmlns:ptdf="urn:com.workday/peci/tdf">005907</ptdf:FileID>
                </peci:Additional_Information>
            </peci:Effective_Change>
        </peci:Worker>
    </peci:Workers_Effective_Stack>
</peci:Worker_Effective_Stack_Aggregate>
```

I want to bring all the peci:Time_Tracking under single peci:Effective_Change and sum the  peci:Time_Tracking based on peci:External_Payroll_Code
I want this to happen please can someone help here?

## Desired Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<peci:Worker_Effective_Stack_Aggregate xmlns:peci="urn:com.workday/peci">
    <peci:Workers_Effective_Stack xmlns:peci="urn:com.workday/peci">
        <peci:Summary>
            <peci:Integration_Event>c6d63dc4fdef100c76819f66b6b40000</peci:Integration_Event>
            <peci:Integration_Sent_On>2022-08-04T09:41:28.451-07:00</peci:Integration_Sent_On>
            <peci:Payroll_Company_ID>FP9_PayGroup</peci:Payroll_Company_ID>
            <peci:Payroll_Company_Name>Test</peci:Payroll_Company_Name>
            <peci:Payroll_Company_Code>FP9</peci:Payroll_Company_Code>
            <peci:Pay_Group_ID>SAL6</peci:Pay_Group_ID>
            <peci:Pay_Group_Name>USA Hourly</peci:Pay_Group_Name>
            <peci:Pay_Group_Country>US</peci:Pay_Group_Country>
            <peci:Pay_Group_Code>SAL6</peci:Pay_Group_Code>
            <peci:Pay_Period_Start>2022-07-25-07:00</peci:Pay_Period_Start>
            <peci:Pay_Period_End>2022-08-08-07:00</peci:Pay_Period_End>
            <peci:Updated_From>2022-08-01T21:00:00.000-07:00</peci:Updated_From>
            <peci:Updated_To>2022-08-04T09:41:28.451-07:00</peci:Updated_To>
            <peci:Effective_From>2022-07-25-07:00</peci:Effective_From>
            <peci:Effective_To>2022-08-08-07:00</peci:Effective_To>
            <peci:Change_Detection>Include only changes entered since the last successful run.</peci:Change_Detection>
            <peci:First_Primary_Run_of_Pay_Period>0</peci:First_Primary_Run_of_Pay_Period>
            <peci:Ad_Hoc_Run>1</peci:Ad_Hoc_Run>
            <peci:Full_Snapshot>0</peci:Full_Snapshot>
            <peci:Worker_Count>1</peci:Worker_Count>
            <peci:Version>1</peci:Version>
        </peci:Summary>
        <peci:Worker>
            <peci:Worker_Summary>
                <peci:WID>25d029d887251010f83dc895aa6a0000</peci:WID>
                <peci:Employee_ID>123567</peci:Employee_ID>
                <peci:Name>Mickey Mouse</peci:Name>
            </peci:Worker_Summary>
            <peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="2">
                <peci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
                <peci:Effective_Moment>2022-07-18T00:00:00.000-07:00</peci:Effective_Moment>
                <peci:Entry_Moment>2022-08-04T05:39:14.444-07:00</peci:Entry_Moment>
                <peci:Time_Tracking peci:isUpdated="1">
                    <peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>TimeTrack_Regular</peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>
                    <peci:External_Payroll_Code>RG</peci:External_Payroll_Code>
                    <peci:Override_Rate>0</peci:Override_Rate>
                    <peci:Time_Tracking_Entry peci:isUpdated="1">
                        <peci:Quantity>65</peci:Quantity>
                    </peci:Time_Tracking_Entry>
                </peci:Time_Tracking>
                <peci:Time_Tracking peci:isUpdated="1">
                    <peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>TimeTrack_OT1.5</peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>
                    <peci:External_Payroll_Code>OT</peci:External_Payroll_Code>
                    <peci:Override_Rate>0</peci:Override_Rate>
                    <peci:Time_Tracking_Entry peci:isUpdated="1">
                        <peci:Quantity>29</peci:Quantity>
                    </peci:Time_Tracking_Entry>
                </peci:Time_Tracking>
                <peci:Additional_Information>
                    <peci:WorkerID>25d029d887251010f83dc895aa6a0000</peci:WorkerID>
                    <ptdf:FileID xmlns:ptdf="urn:com.workday/peci/tdf">005907</ptdf:FileID>
                </peci:Additional_Information>
            </peci:Effective_Change>
        </peci:Worker>
    </peci:Workers_Effective_Stack>
</peci:Worker_Effective_Stack_Aggregate>
```

I tried several ways of group by and template matches but not getting desired results.

Comment: Perhaps cut down your samples to the minimum data to represent the problem, then show us your best grouping attempt for that data and how it failed, i.e. the wrong output you got or the error messages you got.

Comment: I'll reinforce that. You're much more likely to get help if the input and output can be viewed on a single screen without scrolling. And consider shortening the element names: anything that makes the problem stand out clearly. You'll find it becomes clearer to you as well.